# I want to display on all bars of a chart with label.new

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to display on all bars of a chart with label.new.
Please tell me how to display it on more than 500 bars.

Answer (score 0):

If are able to draw those labels without any dynamic positioning needed, you can use the `plotshape()` function instead. You can even plot something with an offset by using its `offset` argument.

If you really need to use a `label`, the maximum you can have is `500`.